# AWS SAM CLI DEPLOYMENT - Issues Parsing Out of the Box secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-sam-cli

I am very green when it comes to Python - so bare with me.
Using the out of the Box Python3 Sample Code provided by AWS to return the 'SecretString' from the AWS: Secrets Manager Service.

No issues there .. I get the returned object (note I have blanked out some details)

```json
{"username":"postgres","password":"XXXXXXXXX","engine":"postgres","host":"srdataset.XXXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com","port":5432,"dbInstanceIdentifier":"srdataset"}
```

detail are all correct.

I am then using `json.loads()` to parse the above into my next function so I can extract the details like so

```py
    # request details
    login_details = get_secret("pg_srdataset_login_details")

    # load json
    y = json.loads(login_details)

    # extract result is a Python dictionary:
    print(y["username"])
```

This again all works fine in my IDE (PyCharm).  I can run the code, build in a Docker container .. and I then use the PyCharm AWS SAM CLI to deploy the code to the cloud .. no issues.

However when I test the function in AWS the code bugs out on the line `y = json.loads(login_details)` step.

the error being ..

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/update_sp_changes.py\", line 229, in lambda_handler\n    y = json.loads(login_details)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py\", line 357, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py\", line 337, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py\", line 355, in raw_decode\n    raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None\n"
  ]
}
```

To test this I also copied the JSON 'SecretString' returned from AWS, hard coded it as a variable, then passed this variable directly into the `y = json.loads(login_details) step`. Tested again and works a treat.

What am I doing wrong - how can I work around this issue.

Comment: May be just a problem of quotation or something. Can you share which AWS doc you're referring? I don't think there is `get_secret`  in built-in functions.

Comment: To clarify.  I can successfully connect to and retrieve a response from the AWS Secrets Manager Service.  The issue I have is parsing the json string using json.loads() which is running as part of a aws lambda function which is giving me the error.  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error but json.loads() worked in Lambda console. I'm not sure why your cli and sam case work, but you might copied output of dict as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I'd share Lambda print debug code.

Preparation:

- from the Lambda-py38 initial state, SecretsManagerReadWrite policy is attached to Lamda
- set `SecretId` and `VersionId`

Output:

- `json.loads()` works for `plaintext`
- print() output almost the same for `plain_text`:str and `secret_dict`:dict. (Difference is quotation:single/double. *Which are treated as the same string* when copy-pasted.)

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

    response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId='arn:aws:secretsmanager:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        VersionId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        VersionStage='AWSCURRENT'
    )

    print("type of response: ", type(response))
    print("response: ", response)

    plaintext = response['SecretString']
    print("type of plaintext: ", type(plaintext))
    print("plaintext: ", plaintext)

    secret_dict = json.loads(plaintext)
    print("type of secret_dict: ", type(secret_dict))
    print("secret_dict: ", secret_dict)

    return 200
```

Comment: make sure the "SecretsManagerReadWrite policy is attached to Lamda".  turns out this is why the response was returning as null .. it was not the code .. it was the missing permission.  a trap for a young player.  Fixed .. now we move on.  Thanks